# How to interrupt wait coroutine in a loop c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a basic game and I stuck. The idea is creating a random numbers array and printing numbers to the screen and asking the user to click buttons according to the rule. For example the rule may be: click the left button if the number is even and click the right button if the number is odd. User got 2 seconds to answer for each number and after two seconds the next number prints. If the user clicks a button before 2 seconds the answer is saved in an array and next number prints(without waiting 2 seconds to complete). The problem is I could not implement a wait coroutine with cancelWait variable in a loop. It looks like in the loop all coroutines are fired simultaniously for some reason . Here is my code:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;

 public class DemoGM : MonoBehaviour {

 int[] numberArray = new int[10];
 public Text mainText;
 private float waitSystem;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         numberArray[i] = Random.Range(0, 10);
         print(numberArray[i]);
     }
     StartGame();
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {

 }

 void StartGame() {
     StartCoroutine(PrintNumbers());
 }

 IEnumerator PrintNumbers() {

     mainText.text = "Rule";
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         mainText.text = numberArray[i].ToString();
         StartCoroutine(WaitForSecondsOrTap(3));
     }

 }

 public void OddButtonClicked() {
     //Save Answer
     cancelWait();
 }
 public void EvenButtonClicked()
 {
     //Save Answer
     cancelWait();
 }


 IEnumerator WaitForSecondsOrTap(float seconds)
 {
     waitSystem = seconds;
     while (waitSystem > 0.0)
     {
         waitSystem -= Time.deltaTime;
         yield return 0;
     }
 }
 private void cancelWait()
 {
     waitSystem = 0.0f;
 }
```

}

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StartCoRoutine()` returns pretty much immediately, so yes, all of your coroutines in the loop will begin immediately and will execute concurrently.  What if instead, in `StartGame()` you start an `InvokeRepeating()` with repeat set to 2 seconds that calls a routine that prints a new number, using a class variable for the index.  The index would be incremented either just before or just after printing the number, as well as whenever the user clicks the mouse button.  Also, whenever a mouse button is clicked, you could use `cancelInovke()` to cancel the current `InvokeRepeating()` and issue a new `InvokeRepeating()` with `0` for the initial delay and 2 for the repeat delay.

I may have missed something in there, but I think that will get you close to what you are after.  Sounds like a fun game.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. That worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to interrupt a a coroutine function. You can exit from a  coroutine function with `yield break`. Setting the `waitSystem` variable to `0` *like you did* to exit that `WaitForSecondsOrTap` coroutine function **should** work but it is better to use the [`StopCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html) function for this.

Start the `WaitForSecondsOrTap` coroutine, get the reference of it which the the [`StopCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html) function returns, when you need to stop it, pass that reference to the [`StopCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html) function. You can also use that variable to `yield` or wait for that coroutine to finish.

> It looks like in the loop all coroutines are fired simultaniously for
>   some reason

This is because your for loop is not waiting for each `WaitForSecondsOrTap` call to finish. To wait for each `WaitForSecondsOrTap` call, yield it. So,  `StartCoroutine(WaitForSecondsOrTap(3));` should be `yield return StartCoroutine(WaitForSecondsOrTap(3));`

This is what that code should look like. It shows proper way to stop a corutine and also prevent `WaitForSecondsOrTap` from being called until the current call has finished or returned.:

```
Coroutine waitCoroutine;

void StartGame()
{
    StartCoroutine(PrintNumbers());
}

IEnumerator PrintNumbers()
{

    mainText.text = "Rule";
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        mainText.text = numberArray[i].ToString();

        //stop old coroutine
        cancelWait();

        //Start new one then return a reference of it
        waitCoroutine = StartCoroutine(WaitForSecondsOrTap(3));

        //Wait for this instance of coroutine to finish then continue with the program
        yield return waitCoroutine;
    }

}

public void OddButtonClicked()
{
    //Save Answer
    cancelWait();
}
public void EvenButtonClicked()
{
    //Save Answer
    cancelWait();
}


IEnumerator WaitForSecondsOrTap(float seconds)
{
    waitSystem = seconds;
    while (waitSystem > 0.0)
    {
        waitSystem -= Time.deltaTime;
        yield return 0;
    }
}
private void cancelWait()
{
    if (waitCoroutine != null)
        StopCoroutine(waitCoroutine);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your answer. I tried this and as you stated the coroutine stops but the next number does not print and the next coroutine does not fire. I am trying to make it work but no chance so far.